# Managing many Python projects/virtualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

In my workplace, I have to manage many (currently tens, but probably hundreds eventually) Python web applications, potentially running various frameworks, libraries, etc (all at various versions).  Virtualenv has been a lifesaver in managing that so far, but I'd still like to be able to manage things better, particularly when it comes to managing package upgrades.

I've thought of a few scenarios

Option 1:
Install all required modules for each project in each virtualenv using pip, upgrade each individually as necessary.  This would require a significant time cost for each upgrade and would require additional documentation to keep track of things.  Might be facilitated by some management scripting.

Option 2:
Install all libraries used by any application in a central repository, use symlinks to easily change versions once for all projects.  Easy upgrades and central management, but forgoes some of the nicest benefits of using virtualenv in the first place.

Option 3:
Hybridize the above two somehow, centralizing the most common libraries and/or those likely to need upgrades and installing the rest locally to each virtualenv.

Does anyone else have a similar situation?  What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using zc.buildout.  It's more annoying to set up than plain pip/virtualenv, but it gives you more opportunities for automation.  If the disk space usage isn't an issue, I'd suggest you just keep using individual environments for each project so you can upgrade them one at a time.

Comment: It looks like buildout does offer some pretty good tools for this kind of thing.  I'll have to look into it a little more deeply to see how it would work for automating our issues.

Answer (score 0):

We have a requirements.pip file at our project root that contains the packages for pip to install, so upgrading automatically is relatively easy. I'm not sure symlinking would solve the issue - it will make it harder to make upgrades to a subset of your projects. If diskspace isn't an issue, and you can write some simple scripts to list and upgrade packages, I'd stick with virtualenv as-is.